# DownThemAll extension randomly starts on its own

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-extensions

I am using Firefox 4 on Linux with the DownThemAll extension. On random occasions DownThemAll will start on its own against my will, such as:

- When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering a link in the address bar
- When I click an entry from the address bar
- When I click a link on a page

One possible solution might be to remove DownThemAll and reinstall it. However removing the extension doesn't clear any of its settings, so I am stuck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to manually remove the extension according to the [Firefox help](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Cannot%20uninstall%20an%20add-on):

> On the menu bar, click on the Help menu and select Troubleshooting Information. The Troubleshooting Information tab will open.
>
> Under the Application Basics section, click on Show in Finder. A window with your profile folder will open.
>
> Open the extensions folder inside your profile folder.

Now you should see a folder for Downthemall, just delete it.

In some cases, it could save its preferences to a general `Prefs.js` in the profile folder, which you *can*  edit manually, but you should be careful.

That being said, if you still encounter the issue, trying to create a new profile and migrating your data would be easier than fiddling around in the profile folder (because maybe it's not just Downthemall causing the problems).

*Note:* I'm not using FF4 so I can't guarantee the Mozilla help is 100% accurate.